# Query by id in React

Tags: reactjs, baqend

Trying to figure out how to grab a single object from the database, I know its key, in ReactJS.

```
import { db } from 'baqend';

  componentWillMount() {
    db.Companies.load('16747fce-f0b1-422b-aa60-220c2dccac58')
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined
EditCompany.componentWillMount
src/containers/EditCompany.js:33
  30 | }
  31 | 
  32 | componentWillMount() {
> 33 |   db.Companies.load('16747fce-f0b1-422b-aa60-220c2dccac58')
  34 |     .then((response) => {
  35 |       console.log(response);
  36 |   });
```

I'm trying to do this directly in a component, but the project is using the React Starter.  This is like a view company details page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is, that the db is not connected yet and you have to wait for the connection, before you can ask for data. 
There are 2 ways to solve this. The first option is to simply call the ready function the db object provides like this

```
db.ready().then((db) => {
  db.Companies.load(....
})
```

I assume you're not using our react-redux-starter, but a simple Create-React-App. For this case, we just created the react-baqend-provider, that is not documented yet, but you can already install it.

```
$ yarn install react-baqend-provider
```

Then use the baqendProvider, which gets a db connection instance and wrap it around your app in the app.js or index.js

```
import { BaqendProvider } from 'react-baqend-provider'

<BaqendProvider db={db.connect('codetalks17', true)}>
  <YourApp />
</BaqendProvider>
```

Now if you want to load data in one of your component simply wrap your component in the Baqend Higher Order Component provided by react-baqend-provider. This component passes the right db instance to your components properties.

```
import { baqend } from 'react-baqend-provider'
class EditCompany extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { db } = this.props
    db.Companies.load(.......
  }
}
export default baqend(EditCompany)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The wait for the connection to be ready was my problem. I am using your starter, which is fantastic...  but I'm wanting to play around with some queries to verify my data modeling, and want to keep that out of redux for now.  Thanks!

Comment: In case anyone finds this... its easier to just copy the patterns in the react-redux-starter and modify the query there, then use the redux logger to make sure you are getting what you think you are getting.